# Nagios check_ncpa.py not working

Tags: server, nagios3

I have installed Nagios on my Ubuntu server.

I am using it for monitoring of Windows hosts. I have installed `ncpa` client at Windows host and `check_ncpa.py` plugins at `/usr/local/nagios/libexec`.

But when I run this command `check_ncpa.py` it says:

```
$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ncpa.py -V
-bash: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ncpa.py: /usr/bin/: bad interpreter: Permission denied.
```

I have given `775` rights to `/usr/bin` and sub folder.

Comment: "bad interpreter" is the key part. Not the permissions. You are running an on windows created script(?) on linux. Adjust the she-bang at the 1st line of the script to point to a valid interpreter. Or use the interpreter it wants to execute the script on the command line. If you need more: post the 1st 5 lines of `more /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ncpa.py` of the script into the question. There should be a link to where your python is stored.

Comment: I used wget for getting script from nagios website.

Comment: Here are the first lines:

#!/usr/bin python3.6
''''''
SYNOPSIS

''''''

Comment: That should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Edit it and try again ;)

Comment: Now it is saying:

': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.6

Comment: @Rinzwind Please reply

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this error message is usually caused by running a file created on windows, with DOS newlines, on any unix/linux shell.  This breaks the #!, so the 'bad interpreter' since its looking for /usr/bin/python^M (with the CR in it.)  I use dos2unix to fix the scripts.

From the comments on the question it looks like script is trying to load a specific version of python which the host itself lacks.

Another way to test for this is to run the script thusly:

```
$ python ./check_ncpa.py --help
```

If that runs, the issue is likely the #! specifying a wrong path to the python binary.  If it pukes with python errors, its probably the DOS newlines.